# best practice : should i create a new controller or not ? in order to respect a good architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, pusher

I'm working on an application where both notifications and history are needed, and what makes it quite difficult is the fact that there is the notion of 'context'.

For example when the user is in a certain view, he must see only the notifications and the histories related to that context.
There is a controller for each, but when I want to update the notifications in the client side ( live update using the Pusher ), from the server side I need to know the context where the user is.
The solution put in place is to send an ajax request from the client side specifying the context he is in, with the route of course.

Now the question is, in order to respect a good architecture, since the ajax request sends the context which is used for both notification and history, should I create a controller to deal with that ( and then that controller will contact both controllers ) or should I use one of them?.
Thanks

Comment: What are the types of 'context'?  And, does it need to be Ajax for any other reason?

Comment: when the user is in his profile he sees all the notifications, but when the user is in an application view, he sees only those linked to that application.
and yes, the use of ajax is a must, if you have any other alternative in order to send live notifications to a user without reloading his page, i'm open to it.

Comment: I honestly feel like a notification module is supposedly not what a controller is supposed to do, but instead is something that the controller should be *interacting* with. I would make a separate module that is global and accessible by any controllers, then you can do something like:
controller -> notification_module -> server -> notification_module -> controller

Comment: when using Pusher, you cant just use your controller, because Pusher uses his own servers, based on socket technologie, in order to get my controllers in work i have to use ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make another namespace/module for the application scenario and put another notifications controller under it.  The application id must be in the url somewhere, the controller/action would then be a child of that, expecting an `@application` instance to be present for filtering the notifications.

So, you'd have a controller under the top level, but also under the application namespace.  The advantage this is you get two views so you can show slightly different things without having a bunch of conditional logic in the views or in the action methods.

Of course, you can also just have two routes and put the conditional logic in the controller#action, so if there is an application_id submitted, it filters differently, this may be what you're doing now.  I prefer to separate the conditional logic as far back as possible, at the routes, so my controllers are simpler.

The Ajax request ideally could/should be hitting the same controller#action with a `js` format so it's getting the same information and using the same queries, rendering with `index.js.erb` instead of `index.html.erb`.

Comment: First thank you for your answer, i will explain a little bit more.
Both notification and history are used by so many models, not only application, and for each one , i can have up to 10 contexts.
making routes for each, will make the routes.rb just enormous way more than it already is.
the notification and history are in polymorphic association with the models concerned, and they both have their own controllers, there is no logique neither in the views nor in the controllers

Comment: It sounds like you may want something like a polymorphic controller, it may only have index and show actions - require a 'type' and 'id' and respond with a list or single object.

Comment: i've never heard of polymorphic controllers, if you have any good links i'm open to it.
it's more related to respecting the mvc pattern, as i said already, the whole system of both notification and history is already designed and working good.
the question is, should i create a controller that will deal with the context and then he will call the notificationController and historyController, or i can use one of them and then call the other? in other words, the context is commun between the two, so to respect the pattern, i shouldn't call one from the other, or is it ok ?